# htaccess mod_problems

Tags: .htaccess

I have site in root folder `www_root/` (`www.examle.com`)

There is `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.examle.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

also I have subdomain on `subdomain.example.com` in folder `www_root/subdomain`. And there is `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I type to browser `www.example.com/subdomain` - wokring
But if I ty URL like `subdomain.example.com` - not working (only homepage)

Pls help, what I do wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: what are you expectiong of `subdomain.example.com`?

Comment: working subpage in browser http://subdomain.examle.com

Comment: your rewriteRule rewrite subdomain.examle.com as subdomain.examle.com/index.php, what url you want?

Comment: subdomain.examle.com/index.php?=something to subdomain.examle.com/something

Comment: `.htaccess` files are checked in parent directories, you should try to move `www_root/subdomain` outside of `www_root`

Answer (score 0):

You try to substitute apache `VirtualHost` functionality with `mod_rewrite`. It's possible but suboptimal. Consider to setup `VirtualHost` configuration with separate document root for the `subdomain.example.com`

If you for some reason insist on using `mod_rewrite` you can do it with configuration like this in your root folder `.htaccess` (you should remove the `.htaccess` from the `subdomain` folder or move ):

```
RewriteEngine on

# normalization of hostname
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.examle.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# config for www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

# config for subdomain.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subdomain.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

...but again, `VirtualHost` is much better solution.

Comment: sorry this not workinkg - internal server error

Comment: Have created this setup on my dev server and works fine. Are you sure, you don't have other `.htaccess` rewrite rules laying around or some typo in translation from `example.com` to real domain name?